# Regexp recursive find/replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, recursion, reference, notepad++

I am wondering if it is possible to write a Regular Expression in Notepad++, allowing me to modify an SQL INSERT script into DELETE.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

Input:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (xxxx, yyyy, zzzz, ....) VALUES (blah1111, foo2222, 3333333, ....);
```

Output:

```
DELETE FROM 
    table1
WHERE
    AND xxxx = 'blah1111'
    AND yyyy = 'foo2222'
    AND zzzz = '3333333'
    AND ....;
```

I have tried to use recursion, but i don't know how to properly make references for each recursion step.

My actual RegEx:

```
Find script: ((\w+)(?R)?, )
Replace script: (?1) =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do write recursive regular expressions in Notepad++, but you can use macros to automate at least part of the conversion. First you can run the RegEx

Find what: `insert into (\w+) (\([^)]*\)) values (\([^)]*\));`

Replace with: `\2\n\3\nDELETE FROM\n\1\nWHERE\n`

to get the basic structure of the DELETE script with two buffer lines above. Then you click `Macro` -> `Start Recording` and press `Ctrl-Home`, `right arrow`, `Ctrl-Shift-right arrow`, `Ctrl-x`, `delete`, `delete`, `Ctrl-End`, `Tab`, `Ctrl-V`, `=`, `'`, to move the first table column's name in the right position and continue until you have the

```
WHERE
    AND xxxx = 'blah1111'
```

correctly. Then you click on `Stop Recording` and playback the macro until all the lines are generated correctly.
You can also try to add my recorded macro to %APPDATA%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml directly:

```
<Macro name="ReorderSQL" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
    <Action type="0" message="2316" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2306" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2442" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2177" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2180" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2180" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2318" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2327" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2179" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=" " />
    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="=" />
    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=" " />
    <Action type="0" message="2316" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2306" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2300" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2442" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2177" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2180" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2180" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2318" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&apos;" />
    <Action type="0" message="2179" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&apos;" />
    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&#x000D;" />
    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&#x000A;" />
</Macro>
```